# Validation Summary Does Not Show in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I am using two validation summaries, but they don't show error message.While required field validator is working, but validation summary does not show so my problem is that.
I want to show the error message.

```
<div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GrdHiringResource" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="hiring_resource_id"
            OnRowCancelingEdit="GrdHiringResource_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDataBound="GrdHiringResource_RowDataBound"
            OnRowEditing="GrdHiringResource_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GrdHiringResource_RowUpdating"
            OnRowCommand="GrdHiringResource_RowCommand" ShowFooter="True" OnRowDeleting="GrdHiringResource_RowDeleting"
            BackColor="White" BorderColor="#D1B271" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px"
            CellPadding="4">
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" BorderColor="#D1B271" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000000" BorderColor="#D1B271" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hiring Resource name" SortExpression="Location_name">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("hiring_resource_name") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqName" ValidationGroup="update" Display="Dynamic"

                            runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtName" ErrorMessage="Please enter ResourceName">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqNewname" runat="server" ValidationGroup="save"
                            ControlToValidate="txtNewName" ErrorMessage="Please enter ResourceName" Display="Dynamic"
>*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("hiring_resource_name") %>' ></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtdescription" runat="server"  TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%# Bind("description") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Reqdescription" ValidationGroup="update" Display="Dynamic"

                            runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtdescription" ErrorMessage="Please enter Description">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewdescription" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" ></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqNewDescription" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNewdescription"
                            ErrorMessage="Please enter Description" ValidationGroup="save" Display="Dynamic">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("description") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ShowHeader="False">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update"
                            Text="Update" ValidationGroup="update"></asp:LinkButton>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel"
                            Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" CommandName="AddNew"
                            Text="Add New" ValidationGroup="save"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit"
                            Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:CommandField HeaderText="" ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowHeader="True" />
            </Columns>
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" HorizontalAlign="Center" BorderColor="#D1B271" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#663399" BorderColor="#D1B271" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#D1B271" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#000000" HorizontalAlign="Center"
                BorderColor="#D1B271" />
        </asp:GridView>

    <asp:ValidationSummary runat="server"  ID="update" DisplayMode="BulletList" ShowMessageBox="true"
ShowSummary="false" EnableClientScript="false"/>
    <asp:ValidationSummary runat="server"  ID="save" DisplayMode="BulletList" ShowMessageBox="true"
ShowSummary="false" EnableClientScript="false"/>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the problem, set this property to true

```
  EnableClientScript="true"
```

**Update**:Got your problem, it is the validationGroup, either add validationGroup property to validationSummary or remove valiationGroup from RequiredFieldValidators

```
<asp:ValidationSummary runat="server"  ID="update" DisplayMode="BulletList" ValidationGroup="update"/>
<asp:ValidationSummary runat="server"  ID="save" DisplayMode="BulletList" ValidationGroup="save"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you make use of validation groups. Also, create seperate ValidationGroups for both the EditItemTemplate validators and the Footer validators. This will prevent one from firing another. This reference will also help you:

Reference: [Validation Groups](http://forums.asp.net/t/1225344.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting ShowSummary="true" or ShowMessageBox="true"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.validationsummary.aspx

Comment: I already use ShowSummary="true" or ShowMessageBox="true" but its not working

Comment: I didn't scroll over and read that sorry.  Try to set EnableClientScript="true"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.validationsummary.enableclientscript.aspx